# how to know if a string in a text file is in the first line? [C++ ]

Tags: c++, string, file, text, position

I have a text file like this:

> Mario 1234567384
>   Luca 1234567384
>   Sandro 1234567384

With a name and a phone number, I want to do the search with the phone number, that I enter the number and I get the name,if I enter the first number in that way I can get the correct name? ( how do I know if the chosen number corresponds to the first line?)

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line into a variable.

Get your input from the User.

Compare input from User to text read from file.

If they match, the User input is the first line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string name, line, number;

if (std::getline(file >> name, line) && (std::cin >> number))
{
    if (number == line) // you're on the first line
    {
        // name is the name of the first line
    }
}
```